# State updating the component is one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I want to use an array to store the data sent from the database. However, the table's context is always one step behind.

For example, I add 3 datas, : `(Ric History 95)`, `(Ric History 80)` and `(Ric Math 70)`.
However, The first picture was the result after adding `(Ric History 80)`, and the second picture is the result after adding `(Ric Math 70)`.
[image: clicking add after history 80]
[image: clicking add after math, 70]

Here is my code.

```
const Body = () => {
  ....
  const [table, setTable] = useState([]);
  

  const handleAdd = async () => {
    const {
      data: { message, card, tabledata },
    } = await axios.post('/api/create-card', {
      name,
      subject,
      score,
    });

    if (!card) addErrorMessage(message);
    else addCardMessage(card);

    console.log("tabledata in add",tabledata);
    setTable(tabledata);
  };

  const handleQuery = async () => {
    const {
      data: { messages, message , tabledata},
    } = await axios.get('/api/query-cards', {
      params: {
        type: queryType,
        queryString,
      },
    });

    if (!messages) addErrorMessage(message);
    else addRegularMessage(...messages);
    console.log("tabledata in query:", tabledata);
    setTable(tabledata);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("table has changed!", table);
  }, [table])
  
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      /*other elements*/
      { <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Subject</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Score</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {table.map((row) => (
              <TableRow>              
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{row.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.subject}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.score}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>}
    </Wrapper>

    
  );
};
```

I would be very appreciated if some one can help me fix this bug.

Comment: What shows `console.log("tabledata in add",tabledata);`?

Comment: @p1uton the data that is one step behind

Comment: That means your server returns old data

Comment: oh god @p1uton thank you so much i fix it! I thought it was frontend problem